# Alternatives to pandas apply due to MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a function that I wish to apply to a dataframe:

```
def DetermineMid(data, ts):

    if data['U'] == 0 and data['D'] > 0:
        mid = data['C'] + ts / 2

    elif data['U'] > 0 and data['D'] == 0:
        mid = data['C'] - ts / 2

    else:
        diff = data['A'] - data['B']

        if diff == 0:
            mid = data['C'] + 1

        else:
            mid = data['C']

    return mid
```

My df columns are A, B, C, D, U.

My call is as follows:

```
df = df.apply(DetermineMid, args=(5, ), axis=1).
```

On smaller dataframes this works just fine, but for this dataframe:

> DatetimeIndex: 2561527 entries,
>   2016-11-30 17:00:01 to 2017-11-29 16:00:00 Data columns (total 6
>   columns):
>   Z     float64
>   A     float64
>   B     float64
>   C     float64
>   U     int64
>   D     int64
>   dtypes: float64(5), int64(2)
>   memory usage: 156.3 MB
>   None

I receive a MemoryError. Am I using apply incorrectly? I would have thought apply is just iterating through the rows and creating a value mid based on row values, then dropping all the old values as I do not care about them anymore.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.select` i.e

```
m1= (df['U']==0) & (df['D']>0)

m2 = (df['U']>0) & (df['D']==0)

m3 = (df['A']-df['B'] == 0 )

np.select([m1,m2,m3], [df['C']+ts/2, df['C']-ts/2, df['C']+1 ],df['C'])
```

Comment: that's perfect! thank you!

Just quick followup:
1) how do you know to use numpy instead of pandas apply?

2) if I wanted to keep the original and make a new column of these values, should I just do the same thing, then concat the two?

Comment: Yes you can make a new column using this and it takes time to understand the concept of vectorizing a solution give it some time